# Show the terms of a sequence $u_n$ is $0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u_{n+k}^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n$ converge. Show $u_k=0 \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Remark:This sequence is not increasing as $u_n-u_{n+1}=u_{n+1}^2\geq0$.

It is bounded below by $0$.

If we can show $u_n=u_{n+1}$, we are done.

Help!

Comment: $u_1=u_2^2+u_3^2+....=0+0+0...=0$?

Comment: Then $u_1$ is not $u_2^2+...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $u_n=u_{n+1}+u_{n+1}^2$. 
Thus, if for some $N$, $u_N=0$, we are done. Now we assume that $u$ is positive. Hence it is decreasing so converges to some $l \geq 0$ such that $l=l+l^2$ thus $l=0$.

Now, let $a < 0$ be a real number, then $u_{n+1}^a-u_n^a=u_{n+1}^a(1-(1+u_{n+1})^a)\sim -au_{n+1}^{a+1}$.

Take $a=-1$, then $u_{n+1}^a-u_n^a \rightarrow 1$, thus $u_n \sim 1/n$ and $\sum_n {u_n}=\infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, how do you get $u_{n+1}^a(1-(1+u_{n+1})^a)\sim -au_{n+1}^{a+1}$? What does ~ mean? Also how do you get the step after that, can you elaborate?

Comment: I am using Landau (“big Oh”) notations and the fact that $(1+x)^a-1/x \rightarrow a$ (Actually, you can just do the computation explicitly with $a=-1$ to find that $u_{n+1}^a-u_n^a$ goes to $1$. The second point you raise is a consequence of Cesaro’s lemma.